# Pycharm and Unresolved References with a populated __init__ file

Tags: pycharm, python-import

I just installed the fastapi package only to end with pycharm staring at me with an "Unresolved reference" notice like a madman. After doing some digging I found that this package has a populated *__init__.py* and it seems Pycharm has no idea what to do with it. The effect of which is it's unable to follow the code with Ctrl+click prompting me to dive into the files.

Unresolved references underlined in red by pycharm

[image: Importing]

__init__.py

[image: init.py file]

I'd like to point out that there is nothing wrong with this and it is valid python code and that this is not specific to the fastapi package. I'm just wondering why pycharm is unable to follow it. Is there a setting I need to update or some plugin I need to install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed to be a settings issue. What I did was I reset my Pycharm settings to default, restarted, and then resynced my settings and everything worked as expected. I don't know what exactly fixed it but this method worked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by a wrong file type (text?) assigned to `__init__.py` (note a text-page-like icon of the file).

This can be fixed by removing `__init__.py` from **Preferences | Editor | File Types | Text | File Name Patterns**:

[image]

The relevant ticket in PyCharm's bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-43186